# Check whether the value in variable is integer or decimal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a variable as `amount`.

- If amount has value `10`, then I should console log it as 'integer'
- If amount has value `10.5`, then I should console log it as 'float'

Comment: `console.log(~~amount === amount ? 'integer' : 'float')`

Comment: i want to check in if condition

Comment: Ok, well the condition is right there in my previous comment. Figure it out from there.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way AFAIK is to use the remainder operator:

```
boolean isFloat = amount % 1 !== 0
```

This should work in all browsers

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that.